# Five percent circle with fuzzy edge using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, transparency, shading, circles

Consider the following code:

```
% DOCUMENT TYPE
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

% PACKAGES
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[top=1.25in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

% DOCUMENT BEGINNING
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\lipsum
\centerline{%
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\clip[preaction={blue,fill}] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,-2cm); 
\fill[white,path fading=circle with fuzzy edge 10 percent] ( -0.92cm, -5cm) ellipse (8.9cm and 6.7cm); 
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following:
[image: figure]

Here are the two problems:

- How to align correctly the rectangle with the page (there is a small space at the right and I don't understand why)
- How to obtain a 5% fuzzy edge? (because currently if I write "circle with fuzzy edge 5 percent", the tex does not compile)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Unwanted space at the right side

The first issue is just a unwanted space by a line end:

```
\centerline{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Then the `tikzpicture` with width `\paperwidth` plus the space after
`\end{tikzpicture}` is centered, leaving the half of the space at the right side of the paper. Solution:

```
\centerline{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

## `circle with fuzzy edge 5 percent`

The number is not a variable, there are only fixed percentages:

- `circle with fuzzy edge 10 percent`
- `circle with fuzzy edge 15 percent`
- `circle with fuzzy edge 20 percent`

They are defined in file `pgflibraryfadings.code.tex`.
Analogous also the missing `5 percent` can be defined:

```
\pgfdeclareradialshading{tikz@lib@fade@circle@5}{\pgfpointorigin}{%
  color(0pt)=(pgftransparent!0); color(23.75bp)=(pgftransparent!0);%
  color(25bp)=(pgftransparent!100); color(50bp)=(pgftransparent!100)%
}
\pgfdeclarefading{circle with fuzzy edge 5 percent}{%
  \pgfuseshading{tikz@lib@fade@circle@5}%
}
```

The only value, which needs to be recalculated for 5 percent is `23.75bp`. Its 5 percent smaller than the following `25bp`.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=1.25in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareradialshading{tikz@lib@fade@circle@5}{\pgfpointorigin}{%
  color(0pt)=(pgftransparent!0); color(23.75bp)=(pgftransparent!0);%
  color(25bp)=(pgftransparent!100); color(50bp)=(pgftransparent!100)%
}
\pgfdeclarefading{circle with fuzzy edge 5 percent}{%
  \pgfuseshading{tikz@lib@fade@circle@5}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[7]
\centerline{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip[preaction={blue,fill}] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,-2cm);
    \fill[white,path fading=circle with fuzzy edge 5 percent] ( -0.92cm, -5cm)
    ellipse (8.9cm and 6.7cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Still I'd prefer not to see `\centerline`.

Comment: @egreg The specification about the vertical spacing before and after is missing. Therefore it must remain unclear, whether `\centerline` is a bad choice or even pretty clever.

Comment: When the method is applied to an asymmetric page layout, the choice of `\centerline` will reveal quite unpractical. Better `\par\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][l]{\hspace{-\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in}<picture>}` with `\evensidemargin` for even pages (and the `ifoddpage` package can decide which of the two).

Comment: @egreg If the centered element just a colored rule across the page, then `\centerline` + a line with `2\paperwidth` should cover the page. Otherwise the question does not clarify, where the faded area should start, relative to the page or relative to the text. It matters in list environments with additional indentations, for example.

Comment: In the case of a list environment one just adds `\@totalleftmargin`.