# Special Smartdiagram TiKz Process Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, smartdiagram

Could you please help me to draw the attached photo by LaTeX accompanied with some clarification texts inside the circles and between the arrows.[image]

Comment: what you try so far?

Comment: I can only normal process diagram by 'smartdiagram' and 'TiKz' packages, but I wish to make something similar looks like above

Comment: You can add a "normal process" using tikz with the circles [use \draw[fill=colorname]  (x1,y1) circle (Radious); and may be some arrows and rectangles].. This way someone is going to help for sure

Comment: Maybe not for absolutely sure, but much more likely. Right now this is just a do-it-for-me-I-can't-be-bothered. You haven't even given us what you can do. And what sort of explanatory texts? May I ask **why** you are determined to do this in Ti*k*Z? There doesn't seem any pressing reason to do it that way. Just use something like Inkscape if you don't want to spend the time learning Ti*k*Z.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 \documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
 \usetikzlibrary{shadings}
 \usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
 \tikzset{% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/287177/121799
   my blur shadow layer/.style={
     preaction={fill=black,fill opacity=.025,transform
     canvas={xshift=#1,yshift=0}},
   },
   my blur shadow/.style={
     my blur shadow layer/.list={.3pt,.6pt,...,4.8pt},
   },
 }
 \makeatletter%from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245444/121799
 \pgfdeclareradialshading{tikz@lib@fade@circle@5}{\pgfpointorigin}{%
   color(0pt)=(pgftransparent!0); color(18.75bp)=(pgftransparent!0);%
   color(22bp)=(pgftransparent!100); color(40bp)=(pgftransparent!100)%
 }
 \pgfdeclarefading{circle with fuzzy edge 5 percent}{%
   \pgfuseshading{tikz@lib@fade@circle@5}%
 }
 \pgfdeclareradialshading{tikz@lib@fade@circle@2}{\pgfpointorigin}{%
   color(0pt)=(pgftransparent!100); color(18.75bp)=(pgftransparent!100);%
   color(22bp)=(pgftransparent!0); color(40bp)=(pgftransparent!0)%
 }
 \pgfdeclarefading{circle with fuzzy edge 2 percent}{%
   \pgfuseshading{tikz@lib@fade@circle@2}%
 }
 \makeatother
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\bfseries\sffamily]
  \node[draw=gray!50,line width=0.5mm,circle,fill=blue!30, minimum width=3cm, 
  align=center, text width=3cm, text=white, font=\bfseries\sffamily\Large,
  my blur shadow] (MWE) at (0,0)
  {MWE};
  \foreach \Angle/\Color/\Label in
  {90/blue!80!white/M,210/orange/W,330/green!60!blue/E}
  {
  \node[draw=gray!50,line width=0.5mm,circle,
  left color=\Color,right color=\Color !60!black, minimum width=2cm, 
  align=center, text=white, font=\bfseries\sffamily\Large,
  my blur shadow] (\Label) at (\Angle:2.4cm)
  {\Label};
  }
  \draw[ultra thick,latex-latex] (M) to [bend right=30] 
  node[midway,fill=white,sloped]{minimal}(W);
  \draw[ultra thick,latex-latex] (W) to [bend right=30] 
  node[midway,fill=white,sloped]{working}(E);
  \draw[ultra thick,latex-latex] (E) to [bend right=30] 
  node[midway,fill=white,sloped]{example}(M);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

This picture shows what is missing in your question. ;-)

Comment: Wow, so amazing, I am really impressed :))))))